# Email class in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I have problem with email class in codeigniter framework.

```
$email = (string)$this->input->post('email');
        $name = (string)$this->input->post('name');
        $text = (string)$this->input->post('text');
        $to = "my mail address";
        $title = "Title";

$this->email->from($email, $name);
$this->email->to($to); 

$this->email->subject($title);
$this->email->message($text);   

$this->email->send();
```

It doesn't work. I get this message to my e-mail , when i try sending email.

```
This is the mail system at host postlady.000webhost.com.

    I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
    be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

    For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.

    If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
    delete your own text from the attached returned message.

                       The mail system

    <g-o-g-u@tlen.pl>: host mx13.o2.pl[193.17.41.15] said: 550 Bad SPF records
    for
        [tlen.pl:31.170.163.248],
```

Classic PHP function mail($to, $title, $msg, $headers); works very well.

Maybe should I config this class?

```
$config['protocol'] = 'mail';
$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

$this->email->initialize($config);
```

I use default config, so maybe here is the problem?

Thanks for help,

Comment: Some host doesn't allow you send mails using php if their mail is not from their host either in from or to field.For example they want from field to be something@host.com.

Here host.com is your host.Give me more details if this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the host doesn't allow you to send email with from header set to anything. Try using a sender email (From header) that the host allows.

When you are testing with mail() you are probably using just that.

Comment: $this->email->from($headers) doesn't work. $headers is the same like in mail(); function